# How to disable keyboard shortcuts on an embedded dailymotion video?

Tags: dailymotion-api

I have read the dailymotion api and saw all the [parameters](https://developer.dailymotion.com/player/#player-parameters) that it accepts,
but I can't find a parameter to disable keyboard shortcuts like UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT.

Is there a query parameter to disable keyboard shortcuts? (something like [disablekb](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#disablekb) that the youtube api offers)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, to date, there is no parameter to disable keyboard shortcuts mainly for accessibility concern.
Are they causing any problem in your integration? Do you have a use case to share?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, appreciate it :)